# Initialization all properties in a Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to initialize all public properties of generic type.
I've written the following method :

```
public static void EmptyModel<T>(ref T model) where T : new()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        Type myType = property.GetType().MakeGenericType();
        property.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(myType));//Compile error
    }
}
```

but it has a compile error

how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three problems here:

- [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue.aspx) takes two arguments, a reference to an object of to set the property on (or `null` for static properties)`, and the value to set it too.
- `property.GetType()` will return `PropertyInfo`. To get the type of the property itself, you want to use [`property.PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) instead.
- Your code doesn't handle cases when there is no parameterless constructor on the property type. You can't get too fancy here without radically changing the way you're doing things, so in my code, I'll initialize the property to `null` if no parameterless constructor is found.

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
public static T EmptyModel<T>(ref T model) where T : new()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        Type myType = property.PropertyType;
        var constructor = myType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (constructor != null)
        {
            // will initialize to a new copy of property type
            property.SetValue(model, constructor.Invoke(null));
            // or property.SetValue(model, Activator.CreateInstance(myType));
        }
        else
        {
            // will initialize to the default value of property type
            property.SetValue(model, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if property doesn't have constructor. e.g: if property is String this exception has occurred : `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: @Mohammad `Activator.CreateInstance` only works with types with parameterless constructors (at least the way you're calling it). See my updated answer for an alternative. This would make any string properties initialized to `null`.